cisco Shaper konfiguration for specific Serviceprovider SLA
given is a GigabeitEthernet based Internet access. The Provider is Policing the Interface to 400MBit/s and allows a maximum Burst of 60kBytes.
I'm trying to configure a Cisco ISR1000 Router as a CPE to utilize this internet Access. While downstream traffic nearly reaches the expected 400MBit/s the upload is far beyond. The circuit provider tells me that i'm exceeding the allowed 60k Burst.
How can i perform a Traffic shaping on the ISR1000 that avoids overexceeding this 60kBytes of burst?
a shape average 350M results in minimum configurable Bc of 1400kBit -> 175kBytes wis is way more than the Provider is accepting.
It seems that it is not possible to configure Tc values below 1/8s on any ISR or Cat8000 branch router from Cisco.
 Configured shape BC value results in the interval being out of range.
 Allowed BC value for given CIR of 350000000 should be at least 1400000.

Any suggestions how to solve this? Is it posssible to adjist the minimum Bc on a Platform level (Platforms are ISR1100, Cat8200L or ISR4300).
EDIT:
Calculated something weidly Wrong, Minimum TC on a Cisco is 4ms, not 125ms.

60 kbit bursts? That would mean a burst every .15 ms - sounds braindead to me. You should ask the provider for an acceptable configuration for a common router - let's see if they can come up with one.

Sorry, had a mixup of Bits and Bytes, fixed this in the post above.
Minimum TC on a ciso is 4ms
the burst on the Layer2 Service Policer is Time-independent (and so independend from the CAR)
So a 60kByte Bc on a 400MBit/s CAR results in a required Tc of 1,2ms
